# tabs stopped working in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

these are a clickable tabs in the Entrada WordPress theme, it stopped working suddenly over time, anybody knows what is the reason and how to fix this?

check this link:
https://tourexegypt.com/product/ras-mohammed-national-park-cruise-and-snorkeling-tour

and try click on the tabs >> Itinerary ,, FAQs & Reviews ,, Gallery

you ill find it redirects without showing the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have visited the link you provided.

The problem occurs because there is an overlap between the main navigation menu and the navigation below it.

tags still work fine if you scroll through the menu down and away from the main menu.

[please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFEVy.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).